# How do I get the commandline that started the process

Tags: java, command-line, environment-variables

From Java, is it possible to get the complete commandline with all arguments that started the application?

`System.getEnv()` and `System.getProperties()` do not appear to contain the values.

Comment: do you mean the arguments provided to the jvm also ? there's a question related to that 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Some of it is available from the RuntimeMXBean, obtained by calling [`ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getRuntimeMXBean())

You can then, for example call [`getInputArguments()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getInputArguments())

The javadocs for which say:

> Returns the input arguments passed to the Java virtual machine which does not include the arguments to the main method. This method returns an empty list if there is no input argument to the Java virtual machine.
>
> Some Java virtual machine implementations may take input arguments from multiple different sources: for examples, arguments passed from the application that launches the Java virtual machine such as the 'java' command, environment variables, configuration files, etc.
>
> Typically, not all command-line options to the 'java' command are passed to the Java virtual machine. Thus, the returned input arguments may not include all command-line options.

Comment: I think this is about the best you can get using pure Java.

Comment: @Stephen Denne ...  Not a fan of this one.  My understanding of the question was to get the command line (say what shows in `ps -f` with the command string.  As the manual page says, "_does not include the arguments to the main method._"  Right now, I'm trying to determine what some other program is passing to a `main` that is not visible to my class.

Answer (score 6):

Since [Java 9](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/102) you may use [ProcessHandle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) to get the command line of the process:

```java
ProcessHandle.current().info().commandLine()
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows, the returned optional is always empty.

Comment: Linux will truncate the command line at 4K bytes which limits the effectiveness of this approach. `info().arguments()` in this case also seems to quietly return `Optional.empty()`.

Answer (score 5):

In Linux that should be possible when you get the output of that command (run in a shell)

```
cat /proc/$PPID/cmdline
```

But that is not portable at all and should therefore not be used in Java...

Comment: Ok, thanks. It is ok if it is not portable, however I need it to work on Windows as well.

Comment: @aksamit - in other words, you need it to be portable between (at least) Linux and Windows ... duh!  @Johannes - "therefore should not be used in Java" is too strong.  It is not totally wrong to write non-portable code in Java ... if circumstances require it.

Comment: @Johannes Weiß: so Sun where just out of their mind when they decided to put *Runtime.exec* in right? I mean, it obviously serves no need at all and should be removed from the language to please the "pure Java gods"? Or ?

Answer (score 1):

The following links may help you get there:

[How to get command line arguments for a running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228386/how-to-get-command-line-arguments-for-a-running-process)

[get command-line of running processes](http://forum.sysinternals.com/get-commandline-of-running-processes_topic6510_page1.html)

[How to get a list of current open windows/process with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java)

Just as a note:

In Windows you have [Process Explorer by Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) that shows you the command line used to open the process. Right click the process and select Properties... You'll see Command Line in the window that is opened.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into how `jps` does this.  It's a Java program that is able to get the full command line for all Java processes, including full class name of main class and JVM options.

Comment: The answer might be right, but it would be much more useful if extended: where can one inspect jps sources? Or ideally include "how `jps` does this` directly in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a environment variable %~dp0 which returns the complete path

Comment: Oops.. I forgot it is in windows. Very useful to run switch to UNC path for a batch file. For Example 
UNC path \\Server\share\folder1\runit.bat 
if the first line of the batch is pushd %~dp0 then your current path will be \\Server\share\folder1\

Comment: That answer is not relevant to why I found this question, but useful to know.

Comment: System.getenv("%~dp0") returns null also on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at YAJSW (Yet Another Java Service Wrapper) - it has JNA-based implementations for various OSes (including win32 and linux) that do exactly this so it can grab the commandline for a running process and create a config that wraps it in a service.  A bit more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java/4465630#4465630).

Answer (score 0):

One option I've used in the past to maintain the cross-platform-shine is to set the command line as an environment variable prior to issuing the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using solaris as the OS, take a look at "pargs" utility. Prints all the info required.