# How do I determine the name of the invoked JAR in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, command-line, command-line-arguments

UNIX shell programs have the convenient property that the first argument is the name of the invoked program.  So I can write something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "You ran $0."
```

And when I run it, I get:

```
$ sh foo.sh 
You ran foo.sh.
```

This is particularly useful when you want to catch a bad invocation and give a usage string, like:

```
Usage: foo.sh -a [AAAAA] -b [BBBBB] -c [CCCCC]
```

How can I do this for a JAR file invoked like `java -jar MyJAR.jar`?  For Scala `main`, `args(0)` is just the first argument passed by the user, not the name of the invoked program.  I want to be able to print out:

```
Usage: MyJAR.jar -a [AAAAA] -b [BBBBB] -c [CCCCC]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541627/how-do-i-get-the-commandline-that-started-the-process

Comment: This only gives me arguments to the java executable, not the JAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
val path = myClass.getClass.getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation.getPath
```

This should work as long as `myClass` is an instance of a class defined in the jar file you are running.