# Get or check JAVA_OPTS

Tags: apache, tomcat, java-opts

I set environment for Apache Tomcat (through setenv.sh)

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m"
```

How can I check this params in JSP or Apache Tomcat Manager Page? I want to be sure that options are working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a RuntimeMXBean from the ManagementFactory:

[How do I get the commandline that started the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541627/how-do-i-get-the-commandline-that-started-the-process)

That will get you the whole command line (except for arguments to the `main` method). You could also look for `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable (and also `CATALINA_OPTS`, which is more useful), but that is an implementation detail: you don't really care about the environment variables... you want to know what options were used to launch the JVM.